# MediaWiki $wgUser to $this->getUser() and $context->getUser() not working

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am learning Mediawiki and looking at some of the extensions.

[Manual:$wgUser](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUser) on mediawiki.org states the global variable `$wgUser` should not be used for new code.

[Manual:RequestContext.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RequestContext.php) says the context object should be used instead, by using either `$this->getUser()` or `$context->getUser()`.

However, when I try to use `$this->getUser()->getName()` in the extension for Who's Online I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/wiki/extensions/WhosOnline/WhosOnlineHooks.php on line 19
```

And when I change it to `$context->getUser()->getName()` I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on null in /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/wiki/extensions/WhosOnline/WhosOnlineHooks.php on line 19
```

The full [Extension:WhosOnline](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WhosOnline) can be found at Mediawiki, but here's the specific page:

```
    class WhosOnlineHooks {

    // update online data
    public static function onBeforePageDisplay() {
        global $wgUser;

        // write to DB (use master)
        $dbw = wfGetDB( DB_MASTER );
        $now = gmdate( 'YmdHis', time() );

        // row to insert to table
        $row = array(
            'userid' => $wgUser->getId(),
            'username' => $wgUser->getName(),
            'timestamp' => $now
        );

        $method = __METHOD__;
        $dbw->onTransactionIdle( function() use ( $dbw, $method, $row ) {
            $dbw->upsert(
                'online',
                $row,
                array( array( 'userid', 'username' ) ),
                array( 'timestamp' => $row['timestamp'] ),
                $method
            );
        } );

        return true;
    }

    public static function onLoadExtensionSchemaUpdates( $updater ) {
        $updater->addExtensionUpdate( array( 'addTable', 'online',
            __DIR__ . '/whosonline.sql', true ) );
        return true;
    }
}
```

How exactly should it be done?

BTW, I'm using Mediawiki 1.28.0.

Comment: Well, `$this` / `$context` must exist before you can call methods on it. It seems your real question is "how do objects work in PHP?", and reading [the PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) is the best way to learn that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page you linked (*Working with Request Contexts* > *When using hooks*): *If your hook provides an OutputPage as an argument make use of the context provided by it.* [BeforePageDisplay](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforePageDisplay) does provide an OutputPage, so just use its `getUser()` method.

Comment: OK, I got there, but I do need to read more on PHP objects.  Here was the eventual code:

`public static function onBeforePageDisplay( $wgOut )`

and 

`'userid' => $wgOut->getUser()->getId(),` and `'username' => $wgOut->getUser()->getName(),`.

I also deleted `global $wgUser;`.

Comment: You should probably call it `$out`, the `wg` prefix is conventionally reserved for global variables.